# Can't apk add python on termux ios

Tags: python, ios, termux

```
iPhone:~# apk add python
ERROR: unable to select packages:
  python (no such package):
    required by: world[python]
```

Comment: Have you tried `apk add python3` ?

Answer (score 1):

do

```sh
pkg update && pkg install python
```